# Belarc Advisor (Store Passwords using Reversible Encryption)

Tags: windows-xp, security, ms-security-essentials

I'm using Belarc Advisor to examine my PC.  Part of BA is a security benchmark summary, which examines components of windows security and provides a benchmark rating.

Two items are marked as Fail:
- Store Passwords using Reversible Encryption
- Password History Size

I have opened the Local Security Settings tool from the Control Panel > Administrative Tools, and ensured that the "Store passwords using reversible encryption" setting is enabled.  Also, I've set the password history to a number.  So I'm a bit miffed about the Fail marks.

Any idea why the Fail marks appear?

Any clues how I can Pass them?

Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Store passwords using reversible encryption" setting should be **disabled** if you want them to be stored securely.